# How to copy only the last value of a split cell into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a string of values into a single column on a new sheet. My code works when there is only one value in the active cell, but will copy every value in the cell once there are multiple values. I want it to copy only the most recent addition to the column on the new sheet. The input is selections from a drop-down menu that allows for multiple selections. I then have these selections being split and offset to a new cell 9 columns over (I also have other drop-downs so that is why there is so much space, but the larger loop should be able to handle the other drop-downs).

This is an image of the input: 
[image: Excel Drop-down Input]

This is what I am currently getting as an output: 
[image: Excel Column Output]

This is my desired output: 
[image: Desired Output]

```
If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & "; " & Newvalue
            Dim txt As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim FullName As Variant

            txt = ActiveCell.Value

            FullName = Split(txt, ";")

            For i = 1 To UBound(FullName)
                ActiveCell.Offset(i, 9).Value = FullName(i)
                ActiveCell.Offset(i, 9).Copy
                Worksheets("Links").Range("A3").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Insert
            Next i
```

I have included only the loop of code that is problematic in order to simplify finding a solution.

Comment: Can you provide the input side of the equation and what that looks like?

Comment: I added a link to an image of the input. I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Please provide a picture showing the desired output as well.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that on a detected change, you want to update a *distinct* list of values in 9 cells over?

Right now you are already managing a single distinct list. All that you would need to do is clear the values in the column 9 cells over then print the values in your drop down.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else:
        If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & "; " & Newvalue

                Else:
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If

            End If
        Dim txt As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim FullName As Variant

        txt = ActiveCell.Value

        FullName = Split(txt, ";")
        ActiveCell.Offset(, 9).EntireColumn.Clear
        For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)

            ActiveCell.Offset(i, 9) = Trim(FullName(i))
        Next i
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But what if I want a distinct list from more than one drop down or ; delimited array? The best way to manage a distinct list in is a Collection or a Dictionary object.

If that is what your looking for, I will update this answer with a way to use those objects.

---

Based on your feed back I have updated the code to below to use a collection object to manage your distinct list from more than one drop down.

```
Option Explicit

Private col As Collection
'  ^ we are defining this to the module level. That means it will retain values
'    and be able to be referenced from any other place in the project.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
    ' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$B$1")) Is Nothing Then
    '      ^ this will make the area your looking more specific than just .row = 11
    '        you could also replace the address with a namedRange
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else:
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                '' My guess is that here you would want to make a call to a function that
                '' removes values from the function. You should be able to loop over the collection
                '' to find the value to remove.
                GoTo Exitsub
            Else
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Newvalue = Target.Value
                Application.Undo
                Oldvalue = Target.Value
                If Oldvalue = "" Then
                    Target.Value = Newvalue
                Else
                    If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                        Target.Value = Oldvalue & "; " & Newvalue

                    Else:
                        Target.Value = Oldvalue
                    End If

                End If
            ManageList Newvalue
            '          ^ you already have the newest value. You just need a easy way to check if it
            '            is in the list. To do this I made a sub that receives text, and checks
            '            if it is in the publicly scoped collection.
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ManageList(txt As String)
' This Sub will receive a text value and try to put it in a collection. 

If col Is Nothing Then Set col = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
col.Add Item:=txt, Key:=txt
'  ^ this method will throw an error if the Key is already in the collection.
'    all we need to do then is watch for errors, and handle if we found a new one.
'    I have found that collections and dictionary objects can handle .5M keys without any issues.
'    using a dictionary, would allow you to test for a key without defining an error handler.
'    with the trade off being that you have to add an additional reference to your project.
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ' we had a new value
    PrintList col
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintList(col As Collection)
Dim printTo As Range
Dim i As Long
Set printTo = Range("e1")
'                    ^ change e1 to a fully qualified address of where you
'                      want you list to be printed.
printTo.EntireColumn.Clear
On Error GoTo eos:
For i = 0 To col.Count - 1
    printTo.Offset(i) = col(i + 1)
Next
eos:
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to make a distinct list of the selections from 8 different drop-downs and copy that list into the A column on another sheet. I am using the same code that you posted here, but I have my larger if loop as 'If Target.Row = 11 Then" in order to loop through the different drop-downs. I also have a copy function within each loop so that the value pops up on the new sheet as the user makes selections from the drop-downs.

Comment: What values am I clearing under the "If Target.Value = "" Then " line? Would it be all of the values in the cell since the user can make multiple selections? I also tried to run the code without this function, but nothing is printing to the new page. I made  Set printTo = Worksheets("Links").Range("A3").

Comment: My assumption is that you will need some way to remove things from your list if one of your dropdowns is cleared or if you you need to reset your list as the collection object will retain some perminance between executions of the change sub.